# VS Code - double clicking word not selecting it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently noticed a bug in the VS Code editor. Usually double clicking on a word selects the entire word. I use this a lot in combination with CMD + D to then select other instances of the word in a file. But its stopped working on my work laptop running 1.65.2.

I do not have the same issue on my personal machine running 1.66.0 but I can't update to this version as updates are centrally controlled by my company.

I've seen a few posts about this online with it affecting other users but haven't really come across any solutions.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I'm running 1.65.2 and it's working for me, double-click selects the whole word then CTRL+D selects the next occurrence. What happens now when you double-click? Seems some of the issues have something to do with `editor.wordSeparators` setting. On my machine it's set to `~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\|;:'",.<>/? (default) in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks for testing on your end firstly. I definitely haven't edited the wordSeparators setting so I believe its exactly the same as yours. It definitely did work fine up until recently. My employer tends to lag behind the latest releases with various software whilst they do security checks on everything. I did apply an update a couple of weeks ago but I'm not sure if this bug was introduced then. But if you have the same version with no issue it must be something to do with my own settings or environment

Comment: just tried with v1.67 (2022-04-06) and double click select the word, no need to double click, if no word selected `Ctrl+D` selects the word the cursor is on and the next time it selects the next occurrence of the word

Comment: Ahh that could be a nice workaround then if I can't get the double click to work again. Just put my cursor on the word and CMD +D